# Selecting from a subset of a list of images

Tags: android, image, android-layout

What I want to do is allow the user to select from a list of 256 images.  Since this will be a lot to display in a single screen, I'm envisoning giving the user a random subset of about 32 images and adding a "load more images" button.  Im having trouble coming up with the XML.

Comment: I understand your problem a little, but you should be a little more specific to give you better support. Similarly you step some interesting links where you can view some examples. Maybe they can help you. [gallery 1](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) [gallery 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

Comment: A RecyclerView can handle displaying hundreds of items pretty easily. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm very interested in having the images be uniformly chosen.  By just displaying 256 in the same order every time a user would be more likely to choose the ones that come up first. Also I'm not 100% sure what that does :P

Comment: A RecyclerView is special type of ListView. Just displays data you can scroll through